# View the xaml of a Windows Workflow file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, workflow, workflow-foundation

I have a file (just a file.  It is not in a solution) that is a Windows Work Flow file.

When I open it I get the GUI interface for WF.  How can I show the xaml under it?  (With out making a solution and adding my file to the solution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the File / Open / file menu item. In the Open file dialog, do not click on Open, but on the arrow to the right of the open button. There, choose Open with... and choose the XML editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply press f7 (or whatever your mapping for "View Code" is).

Unlike with clicking f7 on a WPF .xaml file, which opens both the xaml and code-behind next to each other, for Workflows Visual Studio will close the designer view to open the xaml.